# AWS S3: file not uploading in folder in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new to AWS and we are trying to upload a file using AWS S3 framework in iOS.

Files are successfully uploading in bucket directly. But not uploading the file in the specific folder.

Like we have a bucket as name "TestBucket" and in that bucket different folders as "uploads".

So file is uploading in "TestBucket" But not uploading in "uploads" folder.

I am using below code for upload the files.

```
AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression *profileImageUploadExpression = [AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression new];
[profileImageUploadExpression setValue:@"public-read-write" forRequestParameter:@"x-amz-acl"];

AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];
_mediaUploadTask = [transferUtility uploadData:<ImageData> bucket:<Bucket or Folder Path> key:<FileName> contentType:@"image/jpeg" expression:profileImageUploadExpression completionHander:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask * _Nonnull task, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          // Never called completion when I am uploading file in folder.
        }];
```

Any one can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason is access rights. If your folders do not have sufficient access rights, it will not allow you to upload the image to the folder.

Comment: how to check what is the current folder permission. But in same folder file is uploading using Android SDK.

Comment: My problem is resolved by checking Cognito service permission. The actual problem is Cognito service permission is not attached to AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: @MinuMaster can you please provide more details about Cognito permissions?